# TypeScript singleton generated with a factory function looses typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, singleton, typescript-typings, factory

I have a sugary javascript SDK where the library is instantiated at any given point at runtime, but from then onwards is a singleton. As in, repeat calls to the `default` of the file return the same instance.

My problem is that my typings are lost between the definition of the library and the instantiation.

See this code:

```js
const Factory = (args?: Record<string, unknown>) => {

  return {
    action: {
        method: (code: 'SOME'|'CODES') => console.log('Doing something with', code)
    }
  }
}

let instance

export default (args?: Record<string, unknown>) => {

  if (!instance)
    instance = Factory(args)

  return instance

}
```

If I instantiate the `Factory` directly, I'm furnished with typings correctly. However, the exported interface for the file is attempting to ensure the instance always returns a singleton. In that process we loose typings.

**How should I type `instance` here, in order to retain the typings?**

Constraints:

- I don't want to have to re-type everything in an interface that loosely matches the definition
- The initial instance can be instantiated by the user at any point during runtime (cannot be assumed to be created on bootstrap)
- Shouldn't use classes due to the potential complexity of the nested methods that are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type to get the inferred type of the instance that `Factory` returns, then use that in the type of `instance` and the return type of the default export. See `LibInstanceType` below:

```typescript
const Factory = (args?: Record<string, unknown>) => {

  return {
    action: {
        method: (code: 'SOME'|'CODES') => console.log('Doing something with', code)
    }
  }
};

type LibInstanceType = ReturnType<typeof Factory>;

let instance: LibInstanceType | undefined;

export default (args?: Record<string, unknown>): LibInstanceType => {

  if (!instance)
    instance = Factory(args);

  return instance;

};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgQ2FEAnAnjAvDAFA1AcwgH4AuGAJQFNRUATAHmlQEsxCAaGAVzAGswIAO5gAfAEpsYmAG8AUPJgxU1KD1Rg5S5TCRRW4Cgt2mYAWzUALEPQq5Q9ahQDkAZQDyAWQCiLgD4uAMIeACI+bi5SWDKgkCAANtQAdAkghLguoSDshDAQIJZQVrkwwqzFLtyO1BI6ygC+Ok0NANyKUOgADtQwADKsAEYAkpBQCGDA1AAq3b04NOqasz2MnT0gAGbw+mjoYu3ySbDs0BNTFAMjY+czczD+vGBOm+zU9Idx0DCEalfYMAA9AAqagADy6aFgLwQPASUGBgLwBGI5CotDQTBYuW4fEEInEEkuQ1GZ0mdx60m0OlY21wAEJTuNyXVTEzbgDEMg9vgiBAJIdlKollp2eTDm0gA)

Comment: Wow, I've been using TypeScript for over 6 months now and I still hadn't come across the `ReturnType` utility type. Thanks!